# Understanding how setting color math works from bookofshaders chapter on Algorithmic drawing Shaping functions?

Tags: math, colors, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

[book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/)   has a dozen examples where they set the color in a complicated way

```
color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

Questions:

1. What does they pct stand for, you think?
2. Why does the math subtract 1 `(1.0-pct)`?
3. Why does the math times by color plus pct `color+pct`?
4. How do you multiply a number and a vector `x*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);`?
5. Why does the math multiply a number and a vector?

Full code sample

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265359

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

float plot(vec2 st, float pct){
  return  smoothstep( pct-0.02, pct, st.y) - 
          smoothstep( pct, pct+0.02, st.y);
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    // Smooth interpolation between 0.1 and 0.9
    float y = smoothstep(0.1,0.9,st.x);

    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    float pct = plot(st,y);
    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a linear interpolation of the form

```
interpolated = (1 - t) * source + t * target
```

`t` is the interpolation parameter between `0` and `1`. If it is `0`, you end up with the source value, if it is `1`, you end up with the target value. Any value in between mixes both values. You could use an arbitrary number of values to interpolate between. The important thing is that your interpolation weights sum to `1` (this is called an affine combination and it is the reason why the weights are `1 - t` and `t` in the above formula; `1 - t + t = 1`).

You could also use interpolation parameters `t` outside of `[0, 1]`. This is then called an extrapolation and it is very problem-specific if this notion makes sense.

The GLSL function `mix` already implements this interpolation. So you could replace it with the following:

```
color = mix(color, vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0), pct);
```

You multiply a scalar and a vector by multiplying all components of the vector with the scalar.